# Adding taxes to a total function in Django

Tags: python, django

I have made a model for a cart with products in it

I just added taxes in the model with a default of 0.14 (as an example in order to change it every time an order is made) I am unable to write it in a function that reads from this model and is multiplied by the taxes percentage.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    taxes = models.FloatField(default=0.14)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        amount = models.FloatField()
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        if self.coupon:
            total -= self.coupon.amount
        return total
```

Comment: Is that *before* subtracting the `coupon`, or *after*? Probably *before*, since a coupon can be seen as some part of "payment" I think?

Comment: no I want to create a new Grand Total function after getting the total, this grand total has taxes added to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You multiply the result of the `get_total()` method call with `1+self.taxes`, so:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    taxes = models.FloatField(default=0.14)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def grand_total(self):
        return self.get_total() * (1 + self.taxes)

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        amount = models.FloatField()
        for order_item in self.items.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        if self.coupon:
            total -= self.coupon.amount
        return total
```